# How to open installed iOS app by Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, flash, actionscript

I have developed an iOS app by using Adobe Flash CS6 and installed to iPad. And it's running fine. Now I want to open it from browser by clicking a button. 
The app name: MyRadio
id is: com.radio.MyRadio

I have used the following codes on click a button:
1.
setTimeout(function () { window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/appdir"; }, 25);
window.location = "MyRadio://";

2.
window.open("MyRadio://","_self");

3.
window.location = "MyRadio://";

4.
Lanch App

I tried all the above 4 different types of code. But no one is working. Could you please help me to solve this problem so that I can launch my app by click a button from html page.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your custom URL scheme. Please refer [Launching Your iPhone App Via Custom URL Scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) for more info.

The relevant part of the process from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) is:

> **Registering Custom URL Schemes**
>
> To register a URL type for your app, include the `CFBundleURLTypes` key in your app’s `Info.plist` file. The `CFBundleURLTypes` key contains an array of dictionaries, each of which defines a URL scheme the app supports.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. It's fine for iOS app.
I also want the same functionality for Android app as well. How can I launch the Android app for the same?
I hope for your kind response.